# how can I safely revert 64 bit packages back to 32 bit?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit installation. I wanted to try `multiarch` feature of Ubuntu, so I added 64 bit architecture by `dpkg --add-architecture amd64` and installed 64 bit kernels then booted up successfully. I can install 64 bit applications and run them without problem. Only glitch is it attempts to replace 32 bit `-dev` packages when I try to compile applications ( not library packages). So I have been running my 32 bit installation with 64 bit kernel for ten days. To day I noticed that `Skype` was not running (I don't use it frequently) I downloaded 64 bit version of it and tried to install it with gtk-gdebi. To my surprize I noticed that it removed 32 bit applications and replaced them with 64 bit ones. I immediately killed the process and check out `dpkg log`

```
 egrep  "2017-12-09.*(^| remove)" /var/log/dpkg.log 
 2017-12-09 12:49:31 startup packages remove
 2017-12-09 12:49:33 remove python3-guestfs:i386 1:1.32.2-4ubuntu2 
 2017-12-09 12:49:36 remove libguestfs-xfs:i386 1:1.32.2-4ubuntu2 
 2017-12-09 12:49:38 remove packagesearch:i386 2.7.5 
 2017-12-09 12:49:50 remove apt:i386 1.2.24 
 2017-12-09 12:50:05 remove libguestfs0:i386 1:1.32.2-4ubuntu2 
 2017-12-09 12:50:08 remove supermin:i386 5.1.14-2ubuntu1 
 2017-12-09 12:51:19 startup packages remove
 2017-12-09 12:51:21 remove apt-show-versions:all 0.22.7 
 2017-12-09 12:51:23 remove opera-stable:i386 45.0.2552.898 
 2017-12-09 12:51:28 remove apt-transport-https:i386 1.2.24 
 2017-12-09 12:51:31 remove autopkgtest:all 3.20.4ubuntu1 
 2017-12-09 12:51:37 remove unattended-upgrades:all 0.90ubuntu0.8 
 2017-12-09 12:51:41 remove libguestfs-hfsplus:i386 1:1.32.2-4ubuntu2 
 2017-12-09 12:51:42 remove libguestfs-reiserfs:i386 1:1.32.2-4ubuntu2
 2017-12-09 12:51:44 remove reportbug:all 6.6.6ubuntu1
```

I don't want to jeopardize my system. How can I revert those packages safely?

Comment: if you installed a 64-bit kernel then you are now running 64 bit ubuntu not 32-bit. If you like 64-bit I would convert completely. instead of having a hybrid which is less efficient

Comment: @ravery thank you for responding. I got anxious fearing that I would have to install 64 bit completely. Thank goodness I fixed it by downloading those `removed` packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ into an empty directory then ran `dpkg -i *.deb` installed those packages sucessfully, finally I ran `apt-get install -f` fixed it.

Comment: @kenn Why not post your comment as a answer??

Comment: @kenn -- if you are running a 64-bit kernel, I still recommend converting to 64-bit libraries. the 32-bit ones can not take advantage of the 64-bit code. your current set-up is essentially Hamstringing your install, and can produce hard to trace errors.

Comment: @SMITPATIL though I fixed it manually, I believe there must be an easier way to revert changes.

Comment: @ravery I don't want to switch to 64-bit architecture comletely because I test some apps in 32-bit environment by just editing `grub.cfg` pointing out 32-bit kernel and `initrd` and rebooting, then I have 32-bit environment.

Comment: @kenn -- reasonble, though you should be able to select the 32-bit kernel from the grub menu under advanced options or does grub not list them?

Comment: @ravery I cannot update grub because I boot into  expansion drive which has a few distros installed in a partition using this patch https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/boot_chroot